# How to show that action is happening in a distant past in a manga or comic?

Tags: comics

I wanted to know how can I show that an action/scene is happening in distant past.

My story takes places during two different time periods. The present is the main timeline, but I want to add small segments of past into it. Its something like this: present, past, present, past, and so on.
The main characters have never experienced these scenes, nor do they know about them, but I want to include them to deepen the lore of my world and the story overall.

Comment: It's common to use sepia or grayscale to indicate a prior timeline.

Comment: I suspect there is no objective way of answering this, people will just leave their own opinions as answers. If you really want to be focused on the manga style perhaps ask here https://anime.stackexchange.com/ tagged with [tag:manga-production]

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you want to get is a good contrast, try the **graphic design contrast**:

## Shape

[image: Shape]

## Color: desaturation

[image: desaturation]

## Color: ink

[image: ink]

## Color: brightness

[image: bright]

## Texture

[image: Texture]

## Size

[image: Size]

## Position

[image: Position]

## Style

[image: Style]

Or use an effect like:

## Vignette

[image: Vignette]

<sub>Image from [unsplash.com](https://unsplash.com/photos/S8DFbksQt1E)</sub>